# Ubuntu, How to link .exp file in C?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, apache-modules, linker-errors, apache2-module

How to link .exp file in C? 
I can link .so, .o, .a, .la, lo and .slo files. 
But there is file httpd.h with .exp file only(No .so, .o, .a, .la, lo and .slo files) and I need to use a function from it.
And, I am getting undefined symbol error.

`undefined symbol: ap_cstr_casecmp`

Comment: Try adding `-lapr-1` to your compiler or loader command line.

Comment: Again same error, httpd.h is neither part of apr nor apr-util but apache2 itself, other functions of httpd.h are working fine indeed.

Answer (score 2):

.exp file contains the list of exported symbols only. There is no point to link with it, you need the library to link with.

Comment: This `ap_cstr_casecmp` function is in httpd.h but I am getting 'undefined symbol: ap_cstr_casecmp'. How link it properly to get rid from this error?

Answer (score 2):

[`.exp` is used on Windows only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se8y7dcs.aspx) and is of no use on Ubuntu.  You need a `.so` or `.a` file to link to on Ubuntu.

You need to find the library file (`lib<name>.so` or `lib<name>.a` or similar, where `<name>` is the name of the library) and then link with `-L<path> -l<name>` where `<path>` should be replaced by the path to the directory that contains the library file.  If `<path>` is `/usr/lib` then `-L<path>` can be omitted.

Comment: This `ap_cstr_casecmp` function is in httpd.h but I am getting `undefined symbol: ap_cstr_casecmp`. How link it properly to get rid from this error? There is a file in lib directory httpd.exp in Ubuntu so what is their use then?

Comment: No such a file, other functions from same header file are working fine but this is not.